# Find multiple pattern matches in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

My table data is something like:

```
id    |    text
----------------
1     |  applicationName="App1" some text here applicationName="App2" text again applicationName="App2"
2     |  some text here applicationName="App3" some text here
3     |  some text here applicationName="App3"
```

My output should be like:

```
id    |    text
---------------------
1     | App1
1     | App2
1     | App2
2     | App3
3     | App3
```

**What I tried:** I am able to extract the first matching item for each row using `substring()` and `charindex()`, but I am unable to find out subsequent items per row as shown in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try the following TSQL

<kbd>**[See SQL demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ccefe5/2)**</kbd>

```
--create table t(id int, text nvarchar(max));
--insert into t values
--(1,'applicationName="App1" some text here applicationName="App2" text again applicationName="App2"'),
--(2,'some text here applicationName="App3" some text here'),
--(3,'some text here applicationName="App3"')

create table #temp (rowid int,id int, text nvarchar(max));
create table #result (id int, data nvarchar(255));
insert into #temp 
    select  row_number() over( order by Id desc) rowid, id,text from t;

declare @c int, @d int, @startpos int, @endpos int
declare @textpart nvarchar(255), @datapart nvarchar(255)
declare @len int
set @len =LEN('applicationName="')
select @c=count(1) from #temp

WHILE @c>0
BEGIN
    select @textpart=text from #temp where id=@c
    select @d= LEN(@textpart)-LEN(REPLACE(@textpart,'applicationName="','applicationName='))  
    set @startpos=0
    set @endpos=0

    WHILE @d>0
    BEGIN
        set @startpos=CHARINDEX('applicationName="',@textpart,@startpos)+@len
        set @endpos= CHARINDEX('"',@textpart,@startpos+1)
        insert into #result
            select @c,SUBSTRING(@textpart,@startpos,@endpos-@startpos) 
        set @startpos=@endpos
        set @d=@d-1
    END
    SET @c=@c-1
END
select * from #result order by id asc
drop table #temp,#result
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create UDF for your specific requirement.
I have only written script,you test and convert it into UDF then use cross apply

```
DECLARE @i VARCHAR(300) = 'applicationName="App1" some text here applicationName="App2" text again applicationName="App2"'
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(300)
Declare @delimeter char(2)='="'
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(50))

WHILE LEN(@i) > 0
BEGIN
    IF (charindex(@delimeter, @i) > 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT LEN(@i)

        SET @j = SUBSTRING(@i, charindex(@delimeter, @i) + 2, 4)

        INSERT INTO @t1
        VALUES (@j)

        SET @i = stuff(@i, 1, charindex(@delimeter, @i) + 7, '')
    END
    ELSE
        BREAK
END

SELECT *
FROM @t1
```

Then suppose you created TVF called split then use it like this,

```
select *,fn.* from @t t
cross apply(select * from dbo.split('="',t.textdata))fn
```